# Python multiple text files to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am starting with a number of txt files in a directory.  I want to read earch file and save all the text as a single element of a  list.  I then want to combine each element into a single list.
So for example, starting with 3 text files I want to create a list file with 3 elements each of which is the text from each of the 3 files I started with.

- text 1 = text text text text
- text 2 = more more more
- text 3= and and and

AllinList = [text text text, more more more, and and and]

My approach is to 
* read each text  file and save it as a list file with a new name using the basename from the text file. 
*  Once that is done then I will combine the list files into a single file.

Following is the code that I have produced to do step 1.  The result is a file with all the letters in a single column (Not what I want !).

Help and guidance will be most appreciated. !!!

```
for dirPath, subdirNames, fileList in os.walk(cwd):
for filename in fileList:       
    with open (filename,'r') as fin:
        Filein=[]
        Filein=fin.read()
        #create basename by deleting the file name suffix
        basename=os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        print (' Basename is     %s' % basename)
        #save the file
        with open (basename+' result', 'a' ) as filetowrite:
            for line in Filein:
                filetowrite.write(line + "\n\n")
```

Comment: You can read an entire file into a list in one go with `readlines`. This will give you a list with one line in each "cell". You can then join the list with `'\r\n'.join(mylist)` or `'\n'.join(my_list)` in Windoze or Python, respectively, to get the list into one big long string. Repeat for other text files and create list with 3 variables. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a special character which is doesn't exist in your texts. For example "==="

```
special_char='==='
for dirPath, subdirNames, fileList in os.walk(cwd):
for filename in fileList:       
    input_file=[]
    with open(filename,'r') as fin:
        input_file=fin.read()
        #create basename by deleting the file name suffix
        basename=os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        print (' Basename is     %s' % basename)
        #save the file
        with open(basename+' result', 'a' ) as filetowrite:
            for line in input_file:
                filetowrite.write(line + "\n\n")
            filetowrite.write(special_char)
```

Then when you will need to read the file and get a list of the texts

```
list_texts = []    
with open(basename+' result', 'r') as texts_file:
    list_texts = texts_file.read()
if list_texts:
    list_texts=list_texts.split(special_char)[:-1]
```

I hope that's helping